# Any way of creating an array/vector which contains references to different types of variables?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, reference

I've been banging my head for quite some time now trying to create an array/vector that can contain references to several types of variables, see the example:

```
class Validate
{
private:
   some_array/vector[]; //0 would refer to x, 1 to y, and so on..
   uint8_t x;
   uint16_t y;
   int32_t z;
public:
   Validate();
   void doSomething(uint8_t &member);
   void doSomething(uint16_t &member);
   void doSomething(int32_t &member);
}
```

The whole point is so that I can use this array/vector easily in a "for loop", something like this:

```
void Validate::doSomething(uint_8 &member)
{
   //Do whatever with the variable refered to.
}
Validate::Validate()
{
   for(int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++)
      doSomething(some_array/vector[i]);
}
```

Perhaps somebody have an answer or possibly a better solution for me.

Comment: You may try to use boost::variant for your purposes.

Comment: Vector's are homogeneous, they can only contain one type of value. You could do some ugly polymorphism tricks to do what you are attempting, but the better answer is that you are looking for a std::tuple. If you want to be able to iterate over the container like that, you'll need to use some boost::fusion or boost::hana - esque meta functions. That all assumes you can determine the types at compile-time.

Comment: I am no expert, but the first thing that came to my mind is to create a `vector of void*` I don't know how good is this design wise, but maybe this can do the trick.

Comment: You can't create either a container that contains references or a heterogeneous container.

Comment: @PRP That would be a really bad idea. How would you know what the original type was there? So it's impossible to cast back, and the whole thing is merely useless.

Comment: if you have a common way to process the data you might want to look into polymorphism and create an abstract super class from which all of your data classes inherit, and store pointers to the interface in your vector.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems. Firstly, a container cannot contain elements of different types. Secondly, you cannot store references in a container.

One way of solving the first problem is to use `std::variant` from C++17 (or `boost::variant`). To solve the second problem you could use `std::reference_wrapper`:

```
class Validate {
   using Uint8Ref   = std::reference_wrapper<uint8_t>;
   using Uint16Ref  = std::reference_wrapper<uint16_t>;
   using Uint32Ref  = std::reference_wrapper<int32_t>;
   using MemberType = std::variant<Uint8Ref, Uint16Ref, Uint32Ref>;

   std::vector<MemberType> members;
   uint8_t                 x;
   uint16_t                y;
   int32_t                 z;

public:
   Validate();
   void doSomething(uint8_t &member);
   void doSomething(uint16_t &member);
   void doSomething(int32_t &member);
};

Validate::Validate() : members({std::ref(x), std::ref(y), std::ref(z)}) {    
   for (auto member : members) {
      std::visit([this](auto member){this->doSomething(member);}, member);
   }
}
```

[Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/JAAn12L0KnF37Io8).

Alternatively, you could create a polymophic base class for a member that you can store in a container:

```
class MemberType {
public:
 virtual ~MemberType(){}
 virtual void accept(Validate& validate) = 0;
};

class Validate {    
   std::array<std::unique_ptr<MemberType>, 3> members;
   // as before...
};

template<typename T>
class MemberTypeImpl : public MemberType {
  T& member;
public:  
  MemberTypeImpl(T& member) : member(member){}
  void accept(Validate& validate) override {
    validate.doSomething(member);
  }
};

template<typename T>
std::unique_ptr<MemberType> make_member_type(T& member) {
  return std::make_unique<MemberTypeImpl<T>>(member);
}

Validate::Validate() 
  : members({make_member_type(x), make_member_type(y), make_member_type(z)}) {
   for (auto& member : members) {
      member->accept(*this);
   }
}
```

Comment: I actually got it working with boost tuple, but it turned out that this whole way of thinking turns the code way harder than it has to be, the original task was to decode hex from a string and get a couple of the values from it, this was a completely unnecessary way of doing it when I can literally just read from a substr().

Comment: Thanks for the help though, and sorry for the waste of your time.

Comment: @Tomzter No problem,  I thought about the tuple solution but iterating over tuples is a bit of a pain.